# How can we classify the eigenvalues of this 3x3 matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c c c}
-(A+B) & A & 0 \\
C & -(C+D) & 0 \\
0 & E & -F \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $0<A,B,C,D,E\in \mathbb{R}$. I am interested to describe the real part of the eigenvalues, specifically can it be shown from this alone if they are all negative?

Using the Gershgorin disc theorem we can show that the real parts of all the eigenvalues must lie within the union of the three subsets of the real line
$$
\underbrace{\underbrace{Re[D(-(A+B),A)]}_{(1)},\quad
\underbrace{Re[D(-(C+D),C)]}_{(2)}}_{\Large{\subset \mathbb{R}_{<0}}},\quad
\underbrace{Re[D(-F,E)]}_{(3)},\quad
$$
(where D(a,r) is a disc complex radius r centre a). $(1)$ and $(2)$ are clearly negative subsets of the real numbers, however $(3)$ is only purely a negative if $E<F$. Therefore the Gershgorin disc theorem cannot show this on it's own, could anyone offer any suggestions here?

Comment: I think you mean $F>E$. Anyway, try a numerical example where $F$ is extremely small and $E$ is extremely large.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you for pointing that out! I can show it numerically, however I would like a general proof if possible! As in my simulatoins $E>F$ by a factor of 10, which we do find negative eigenvalues for.

Comment: It does seem to work; I tried the case $A=B=C=D=1,E=10^6,F=1$, and I still get all negative eigenvalues. One thing you might do would be to prove that the determinant must be negative, since you already know two of the eigenvalues are negative, this would imply that the other one is also negative.

Comment: @Ian: That sounds possible! At least somewhere to start. My LA is embarrassingly rusty, how would that proof the third eigenvalue was negative? How is the determinant related to the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: @Ian: Oh, if it's diagnosable it is a product by decomposition?

Comment: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues (with their algebraic multiplicity). In your case, either two eigenvalues are complex and one is real, or all three eigenvalues are real. In the first case, these two are conjugate pairs, so their product is a positive real, so if the third one is negative then you are done. In the second case, two of them are negative reals, so their product is positive, and the situation is the same.

Comment: @Ian: This is really handy, thanks very much! :)

Comment: Actually, I missed a subcase. Case 1: two are complex and one is real. Case 1a: The real one is the third one in your list. Then this one is negative iff the determinant is negative. Case 1b: One of the complex ones is the third one in your list. Then this one has negative real part because it is the conjugate of one of the first two, which you already know have negative real part. Case 2: all three are real. Then the determinant is negative iff an odd number of them are negative (which must be all three, by what you've shown already).

Comment: @Ian: Indeed, luckily that doesn't hurt the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments show how to see that this would follow if one could see that the determinant is negative. To see that the determinant is negative, cofactor expand along the bottom row. You get

$$\text{det}(M)=-E \text{det} \left ( \begin{bmatrix} -(A+B) & 0 \\ C & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right ) -F\text{det} \left ( \begin{bmatrix} -(A+B) & A \\ C & -(C+D) \end{bmatrix} \right ) \\
= -F\text{det} \left ( \begin{bmatrix} -(A+B) & A \\ C & -(C+D) \end{bmatrix} \right )$$

since the first minor matrix is singular. Now this determinant is positive since $(A+B)(C+D)>AC$, and $F$ is positive, so the whole thing is negative.

Comment: Thank you very much! As you have shown it conveniently does drop out through direct calculation. Many thanks for helping me with this, I very much appreciate it.